# How to dynamically use lapply in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have a dataset that looks as

```
set.seed(18)
library(data.table)
site1 <- data.table(id = 1:10, A = c(sample(c(NA, letters[1:10]),10)), 
                    B = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:7]), 10, replace = T),
                    C = sample(c(NA, 1:4), 10, replace = T))

site2 <- data.table(id = c(1:4, sample(5:15, 6)), 
                    A = c(NA, NA, NA, sample(letters, 1), NA, NA, NA, sample(letters, 1), NA, NA), 
                    B = sample(LETTERS, 10), d = sample(1:5, replace = T))
```

and a function that looks as

```
col.smash <- function(a, b, linkvars){
  require(data.table)
  
  ##### CONVERT TO DATA.TABLES FOR EASIER USE, AND MERGE
  if(dim(a)[1] <= dim(b)[1]){
    c <- data.table(a); setkeyv(c, linkvars)
    d <- data.table(b); setkeyv(d, linkvars)
  } else {
    c <- data.table(b); setkeyv(c, linkvars)
    d <- data.table(a); setkeyv(d, linkvars)
  }
 
  k <- c[d]
  
  rep.list<- names(a)[names(a) %in% names(b) & !(names(a) %in% linkvars)]
  i.combo <- paste0("i.",rep.list)

  f <- k[ , (rep.list) := lapply(.SD, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x), 
                                                   get("i.", names(x)), x)}), 
          .SDcols = rep.list]
  return(f)
  }
```

This function's goal is to see what variables are in both `site1` and `site2` and if there is an "NA" in, lets say `site1$A`, replace it with the corresponding value in `site2$A`. There is a hierarchy of `site1` over `site2`, which is why the `ifelse` statement only checks for one variable with "NA".

I am getting an error at the `lapply` function because the first `ifelse` result (`get("i.",names(x))`), after the condition isn't working properly. In doing so, I get the following error:

```
Error in as.environment(pos) : using 'as.environment(NULL)' is defunct
```

which I do not understand. Ideally, what I would get is a `data.table` with all values in `site1` and `site2` with variables `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and not with `i.A`, `i.B` as such,

```
    id  A  B  C  d
 1:  1  i  E NA  4
 2:  2  g  F NA  4
 3:  3  h NA  4  1
 4:  4  x  B  4  2
 5:  5  j  G NA  NA
 6:  6  c NA  3  4
 7:  7  a  D  2  NA
 8:  8  b NA  2  NA
 9:  9  d  G  1  4
10: 10  f NA  1  NA
11: 12 NA  V NA  2
12: 13  n  J NA  1
13: 14 NA  T NA  1
14: 15 NA  X NA  1
```

So I think I really have two problems. The first is the error, and the second is that I am not getting all rows in `k` in my function. They don't seem to be related.

Any help is appreciated.

Also, brownie points for whoever can figure out the **incredible** `col.smash` reference.

Comment: You could do this as an aggregate operation in `by=` groups if you make one long data.table by rbind-ing `site1` and `site2` underneath each other.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about complete columns, right? The wording _and if there is an "NA" in, lets say `site1$A`, replace it with the corresponding value in `site2$A`_ is somewhat unfortunate as it suggests you are asking for _a row-wise replacement_. But in this case, the expected result would show a "C" in row 3 of column `B`, e.g.

Comment: @UweBlock I am not understanding your question. Please clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This function's goal is to see what variables are in both `site1` and `site2` and if there is an "NA" in, lets say `site1$A`, replace it with the corresponding value in `site2$A`. There is a hierarchy of `site1` over `site2`

The output can be had like

```
g <- function(d1, d2, byvars){
  D = funion(d1[, ..byvars], d2[, ..byvars])

  d2vars = setdiff(names(d2), byvars)
  D[d2, on=byvars, (d2vars) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", d2vars))]

  d1vars = setdiff(names(d1), byvars)
  D[d1, on=byvars, (d1vars) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", d1vars))]  

  setcolorder(D, c(byvars, d1vars, setdiff(d2vars, d1vars)))
  setorderv(D, byvars)[]
}

g(site1, site2, "id")
```

which gives

```
    id  A  B  C  d
 1:  1  i  E NA  4
 2:  2  g  F NA  4
 3:  3  h NA  4  1
 4:  4 NA  B  4  2
 5:  5  j  G NA NA
 6:  6  c NA  3  4
 7:  7  a  D  2 NA
 8:  8  b NA  2 NA
 9:  9  d  G  1  4
10: 10  f NA  1 NA
11: 12 NA  V NA  2
12: 13  n  J NA  1
13: 14 NA  T NA  1
14: 15 NA  X NA  1
```

---

*How it works*

The `byvars` argument allows for a vector of column names.

The fairly new `..` syntax allows referencing an index of columns stored outside the data.table. I looked in the FAQ and `?data.table` and could find no documentation. For now, it is [the first changelog item in 1.10.2 at least](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v1102--on-cran-31-jan-2017).

To give the "hierarchy of site1 over site2", we add from site2 first and then site1, so it gets the last edit.

The use of `funion` assumes that there are no duplicates within each table. If there are, a more complicated approach to that step will be needed, probably something like

```
D = rbind(d1[, ..byvars], d2[,..byvars][!d1, on=byvars])
```

Comment: (I don't understand the col.smash reference, nor the function for that matter, so can't really comment on why it doesn't work.)

Comment: @akrun Yeah, there is fsetdiff. Where do you think it fits here? I was thinking about how to use it, but then started over with funion.

Comment: It was a hulk-smash reference. but thanks for this. why is there a `..` before byvars? I don't quite understand that

Comment: Also, nice thing to note is that this works with multiple `byvars`.